# I want to update two tables with one subform based on a query

Tags: ms-access

I am overhauling an old access db that was built with Social Security numbers as PKs which is no longer allowed. So, I have major work to do in relating these tables properly. So, far it displays information well but does not allow additions. Specifically:

In one household can reside many clients. A client can reside in one household. That means a many to many relationship, so I created a union table called Residency.

**Clients information1**

```
Client ID PK
Lastname
Firstnam
Address
```

**Household**

```
HouseholdID PK
DateAdded
```

**Residency**

```
ResidencyID PK
HouseholdID FK
ClientID FK
Active
```

[image]

My form, based on the query:

```
SELECT [Clients information1].ClientID, [Clients information1].LASTNAME, [Clients information1].FIRSTNAM, [Clients information1].SSN, [Clients information1].MI, [Clients information1].ADDRESS, [Clients information1].CITY, [Clients information1].STATE, [Clients information1].ZIP, [Clients information1].PHONE, [Clients information1].BIRTHDTE, [Clients information1].MARSTAT, [Clients information1].RACE, [Clients information1].SEX, [Clients information1].INCOME, [Clients information1].NOINHOUS, [Clients information1].PRINCOME, [Clients information1].SEINCOME, [Clients information1].AGENCYID, [Clients information1].WARNMESS, [Clients information1].ALTS, [Clients information1].COUNTY, [Clients information1].Email, Distribution.Case, Residency.HouseholdID, Role.RoleID
FROM Role INNER JOIN (Household INNER JOIN ((([Clients information1] LEFT JOIN Distribution ON [Clients information1].ClientID = Distribution.ClientID) INNER JOIN Residency ON [Clients information1].ClientID = Residency.ClientID) ON Household.HouseholdID = Residency.HouseholdID) ON Role.RoleID = Residency.RoleID;
```

The subform linked Parent to Child on HouseholdID is based on the following query. I shortened the list for readability (This might be the problem, the fact its based on a query. but like I said is displays current records fine!)

```
SELECT [Clients information1].ClientID, [Clients information1].LASTNAME, ...
 Residency.HouseholdID, Residency.ClientID
FROM Household INNER JOIN ([Clients information1] INNER JOIN Residency ON [Clients information1].ClientID = Residency.ClientID) ON Household.HouseholdID = Residency.HouseholdID
ORDER BY [Clients information1].BIRTHDTE;
```

When I add a new person to the household with this form it adds the successfully to Client table but not to the Residency table. When I refresh the form the person does not list though they exist.

I need to add a record to the Client table and the Residency table with one subform entry. Is this not possible? The relationships are established (I would add an image, if I had enough reputation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to help. But first:

1. Your queries refer to table 'Clients information' without the underscore as shown for the table name at the top of your post.
2. I believe in your Residency table, where you duplicated 'HouseholdID', you really meant to have 'ClientID' (or 'Client ID' since I see that also).
3. I assume (but will need to know) your data entry form MAY have three listboxes (Clients, Household, Residency), plus a means to ADD either Client or Household or Residency.
4. Depending on how you select / add and if your form is bound to a recordset, you will need to add VBA code to add the Residency record WHEN NEEDED.
5. To do that (IMO), you would select a Client, select a Household, then click a button to add the Residency. Assuming you have used listboxes, then the ID's can either be displayed in the listbox or hidden - makes no difference. The VBA code would be like:

   ```
   Private Sub cmdAddResidency_Click()
   Dim strSQL  As String
   DoCmd.SetWarnings False
   strSQL = "INSERT INTO Residency (HouseholdID, ClientID) SELECT " & Me.lstClients.Column(0) & " AS Expr1, " & Me.lstHouseholds.Column(0) & ";"
   CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
   DoCmd.SetWarnings True
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: 1. Yes, the underscore in the description was an error. (subconscious desire to fix that table name with spaces in it!)
2. Correct again.

Comment: 3. I cant wait to get enough reputation to post picture of form. The subform is a continuous form listing each Client information1 entry related by the household ID. The form is set to allow additions so a new record can be typed into the last entry. The household ID for the blank is set by default value to be equal to that of the head of household record selected in the parent form.

Comment: 4. I though of doing this programmatically which would allow me to enter into two tables in a sub but thought I should be able to accomplish without.

Comment: 5. The original flow of the program is to search for a name or client number and the main client form would pop up with the selected individual. That form has several tabs relating to the individual, one of which is the "household listing". However, with this new Residency table the flow for adding a new family seems to logically require a household record be created first, then a head of household added followed by all the dependents in the house (the form would have to "remember" the household just created in a multi user environment).